# Promise returned from onSearch(),onSearchButtonClick() is ignored

Tags: angular

I keep getting the following warning: `Promise returned from onSearch() is ignored` and `Promise returned from onSearchButtonClick() is ignored`. How can I fix it? My code is as follows:

```
  constructor(
    private unsplashService: UnsplashService
  ) {}

  async onSearch(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      return this.searchImages();
    }
  }

  async onSearchButtonClick() {
    return this.searchImages();
  }

  async searchImages() {
    if (!UtilService.isNullOrWhitespace(this.searchText)) {
      this.images = await this.unsplashService.searchImages(this.searchText);
    }
  }

  export class UnsplashService {
    getUnsplashApi(): Unsplash {
      return new Unsplash({
        accessKey: environment.unsplashAccessKey,
      })
   }

   async searchImages(query: String, pageIndex: number = 1, elementsPerPage: number = 30): Promise<any> {
     let response = await this.getUnsplashApi().search.photos(query, pageIndex, elementsPerPage);
     let json: any = await response.json();
     return await json.results;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove async from the two of them. Async declarations wraps promises .. if you already return promise then you don't need them